# fall/fall off/fall down/fall back

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Consider:

> Sales always fall off in the winter months.
>
> Sales always fall in the winter months.
>
> Sales always fall down in the winter months.
>
> Sales always fall back in the winter months.

Are these all acceptable versions? I guess the 3rd one is not. What about the others? which is preferred in common use?

Comment: Why use adverbial particles *(off, on...etc)* when the sentence without it is meaningful in the context? *Sales always fall in the winter months* is short, sweet and to-the-point. Sales fall *off, in, down, back* won't really make **much difference** if you are talking about the regular fall of sales in winter months.

Comment: good read here... http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/fall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are grammatical and would be understood.

1 or 2 would be preferred.

3 would be least appropriate because "fall down" is commonly used for people.

4 is less commonly used.

Other possibilities: Sales always *drop off* in the winter months. Sales always *die down* in the winter months.

Or you could avoid the idiom altogether and say, Sales always *decrease* in the winter months.

Comment: Thx! BTW, let me guess. The reason why you use "would" in your answer is that you are not referring to any actual conversation but only your thoughts about it. Right?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Right!